# mysqli insert doesnt return false on duplicates

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a function that insert new users to a database. If the input is somewhat bad or the username or email already excist i want it to return false.

This is what it looks like:

```
public function input( $username, $password, $email ){
    if( $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" )){

        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $this->mysqli->close();

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine until I try to create a duplicate, it returns true, but doesnt affect the tabledata in the database as I can see.

Comment: Do you have a PK or composite key defined in your database structure ?

Comment: I have a PK named ID that auto_increments.
I also have the attributes email and username set to UNIQUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return !!$this->mysqli->insert_id; // instead of true
```

Comment: Darn, I edited the mysql variable name to mysqli, so now your answer has a typo! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your function only returns false if the `prepare` fails - you're not adding the data until after that.

You can check the return value of your insert statement to see what this is actually returning, to see if your INSERT succeeded or not.

Also, your question title and your tags indicate that you're using mysqli, but your function calls are both for `mysql_*` - is one or another a typo?

Comment: There, fixed it! The function call you were talking about was only a variable name.